# Turning cURL request into PHP

Tags: php, curl, web

Really stuck on how to convert the below into a PHP get request. I can see there is a request URL and header paramters, but not sure how it would look. Please can you lovely people help :)

```
curl -v -X GET \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
"https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/users/me"
```

Comment: Please Read documentation in php.net, good set of examples available

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pretty good examples in the php docs. Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: I get how to create a cURL request, but I'm not sure how to convert the parameters into the right format.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    ));

Comment: Baah. Accidentally pushed enter before i was done, and cant seem to edit the comment. But maybe you get the format?